# How to look inside of firebase database table?

Tags: flutter, firebase

I'm new to flutter with firebase.
I'm studying this flutter CRUD app.

https://flutterawesome.com/firebase-crud-operation-in-flutter/

I can crud sucessfuly with them
and I'm looking my project at firebase web page.

I would like to look inside this database and table.
Could you teach me how to do it please?

[image]

Comment: can you take a screenshot of your firebase console page and include it so we can guide you

Comment: Dear Gwhyyy Thank you for answering me  I post screen shot.

Comment: here on your screenshot, you see that "cloud firestore" card, click it, and it will open a page with a button which it will let you create your database, click it and pass the settings of your database, then a new page will be opened containing your collection/document panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the firebase console the choose `Cloud firestore` Here you have all the data if you created successfully[image]

[image]

Comment: Dear MrShakila Thank you for answering me. I post my page. And I don't see the [Firebase database] button.

Comment: sorry i mean cloud firestore (i edited my answer)